# Creating audio spectrum of youtube stream HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, audio, youtube, spectrum

createMediaElementSource in HTML5 (Draw visualization of youtube video). Is that possible?

Could you show me a example if it is? I just want to add a traditional youtube player and under it the spectrum/visualization, I found a mp3 version on the internet.

Here is a audio/mp3 version of it, I just have no idea if this could work with a youtube video stream.

```
<style type="text/css">
div#mp3_player{ width:500px; height:60px; background:#000; padding:5px; margin:50px auto; }
div#mp3_player > div > audio{  width:500px; background:#000; float:left;  }
div#mp3_player > canvas{ width:500px; height:30px; background:#002D3C; float:left; }
</style>
<script>
// Create a new instance of an audio object and adjust some of its properties
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = '613814.mp3';
audio.controls = true;
audio.loop = true;
audio.autoplay = false;
// Establish all variables that your Analyser will use
var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;
// Initialize the MP3 player after the page loads all of its HTML into the window
window.addEventListener("load", initMp3Player, false);
function initMp3Player(){
    document.getElementById('audio_box').appendChild(audio);
    context = new webkitAudioContext(); // AudioContext object instance
    analyser = context.createAnalyser(); // AnalyserNode method
    canvas = document.getElementById('analyser_render');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // Re-route audio playback into the processing graph of the AudioContext
    source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio); 
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);
    frameLooper();
}
// frameLooper() animates any style of graphics you wish to the audio frequency
// Looping at the default frame rate that the browser provides(approx. 60 FPS)
function frameLooper(){
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
    fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00CCFF'; // Color of the bars
    bars = 100;
    for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
        bar_x = i * 3;
        bar_width = 2;
        bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 2);
        //fillRect( x, y, width, height ) // Explanation of the parameters below
        ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mp3_player">
  <div id="audio_box"></div>
  <canvas id="analyser_render"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this isn't possible because you can't access the HTML5-Video-Element of the Youtube-Iframe/Page from your page.
Unfortunately Youtube doesn't allow CORS which prevents this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe downloading the audio and using [wavesurfer](https://wavesurfer-js.org/) would be the solution? It would solve the issue pointed out by Joriktos. Requires back end though.

Comment: Please expand your answer a bit. Refer to [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)